# How to use a loop to fill in multiple controls on a Userform?

Tags: excel, vba, forms, loops

I have the following code that looks up an ID in a data table and returns the corresponding value from other columns.  Below is the code to return a single column value and post it to the TextBox/ComboBox on my form. However, I am looking to create this as a loop to post to all the 20-30 fields I have rather than repeating the code for each field.

```
col_no = 3 to 29
```

Note that my TextBox/ComboBox have varying names e.g. customer, site etc.

```
id_1 = OrderDisplay.id

col_no = 3
sales_order = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(id_1, Worksheets("Data").Range("A:AB"), col_no, False)
OrderDisplay.sales_order = sales_order
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You could make a table or array with the sources and destinations and loop through them that way.

Answer (score 0):

Consider querying your worksheet data as a database as it seems to be tabular structure where you pass in as a parameter the specific *id*. In fact, this may set you up to upsize your worksheet to actual database like MS Access (Excel's sibling), SQLite, etc. where you can swap out the ADO connection string and then sheet name in SQL for database table!

Below assumes all your userform controls have the same exact name as table fields (first columns of worksheet).

```
Dim conn As Object, rst As Object,  cmd As Object
Dim strSQL As String, id1 As Long

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
                   & "Data Source='C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm';" _
                   & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"";"

' OPEN CONNECTION
conn.Open strConnection

' WORKBOOK QUERY
strSQL = "SELECT t.* " _
          & " FROM [SheetName$] AS t" _
          & " WHERE t.id = ?"

id_1 = OrderDisplay.id

' BUILD PARAMETERED QUERY
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CommandText = strSQL
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("idparam", adInteger, adParamInput, , id1)
End With

' CREATE RECORDSET
Set rst = cmd.Execute

' LOOP THROUGH RECORDSET AND FILL IN CONTROL VALUES
rst.MoveFirst
Do While Not rst.EOF
    For i = 1 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
        Me.Controls(rst.Fields(i).Name).Value = rst.Fields(i)
    Next i
    rst.MoveNext
Loop

rst.Close: conn.Close    
Set conn = Nothing: Set rst = Nothing: Set cmd = Nothing
```